# Reloading a json store with new parameters ExtJs Ext.data.JsonStore

Tags: json, extjs

I am currently having trouble of reloading a json store with new parameters. Here is my store:

```
 newsletters = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: '/newsletters/',
        root: 'results',
        fields: [
             'id',
             'body'
             'recipients'
        ],
        baseParams: { command: 'json', to: dateTo, from: dateFrom },
    autoLoad: true
    });
```

dateTo and dateFrom are initally empty strings ( '' ) and checking in firebug /newsletters is called with the correct parameters.

Now none of the following techniquest work:

Changing the values of dateTo and dateFrom then calling newsletters.reload() still calls the page with the parameters to and from being empty strings.

Calling `newsletters.reload( { to: 'test1', from: 'test2' } );` still sees the parameters as empty strings.

Finally as from the manual I have tried:

```
lastOptions = newsletters.lastOptions;
Ext.apply(lastOptions.params, {
    to: 'test1',
    from: 'test2'
});
newsletters.reload(lastOptions);
```

This again does not request /newsletters with the updated parameters.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if it's crucial or not.. but you missed a `,` after `'body'` in the `fields`

Answer (score 30):

You can actually pass params object to the load() method

```
newsletters.load({
  params: {to: 'test1', from: 'test2'}
})
```

Answer (score 5):

From the docs, you can probably do :

```
store.setBaseParam('to', dateTo);
```

Now, if I understand correctly, you want your baseParams to be changed whenever dateTo and dateFrom are changed.

You could try :

```
var dateTo = '', dateFrom = '';

store.on('beforeload', function(s) {
    s.setBaseParam('to', dateTo);
    s.setBaseParam('from', dateFrom);
});

// This should work :
dateTo = 1;
dateFrom = 2;
store.load();
```

Answer (score 4):

My problem was: I have a store that shall request data over a proxy to back-end. This request shall hold a parameter named `filter`, which will just help back-end to decide which is the set of result the client is interested in. This parameter is loaded from a `Combobox` or some other component which the user can use to express which filter shall be used.

From my point of view the parameters shouldn't be set to the Store and neither using the load parameter. I will explain why:

1. Configuring parameters to the store would imply that every other component using the same store will have this parameters configured, meaning you can have concurrence problems.
2. And on the second case, it is not interesting to have it configurable over load method, because you don't wanna every single time explicit make use of the `load` method by your self, remember that there are already some components like paging and custom components that triggers this method.

What would be the right way from my point of view:

Every time that a `load` is triggered, we just attach the additional parameter in a non-intrusive way. Meaning that the trigger will not need to have any change (remember here trigger could be any component that executes `store.load()`) and the store shall be not aware about this new parameter.

You can see here clearly that this shall be an operation done before request data to proxy, and in my case I implemented as a listener for the `beforeload` event. When `beforeload` is executed, I just aggregate the new parameters to the operation parameter of the listener that according [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-beforeload) is: `beforeload( store, operation, eOpts )`. The final implementation is something like:

```
store.on({
    beforeload: function (store, operation, opts) {
        Ext.apply(operation, {
            params: {
                filterName: Ext.getCmp('filterCombo').getValue()
            }
       });
    }
});
```